# Vectorization using apply family of functions in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, vectorization, apply

I am working with Linear Regression model, and I want to calculate some performance measures manually. I split my data using Leave One Out Cross-Validation (LOOCV).

The following R code give me the desired results but takes a long time since I am using for loop with LOOCV.

Is there a way to rewrite my code in a fast way using, for example, apply family of functions in R?

The dataset is uploaded from [here](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Combined+Cycle+Power+Plant)

```
wdbc <- read_excel("Folds5x2_pp.xlsx") 
wdbc[] <- lapply(wdbc, scale)

   dim(wdbc)

9568    5

   head(wdbc)

1 -0.629 -0.987  1.82  -0.00952  0.521
2  0.742  0.681  1.14  -0.975   -0.586
3 -1.95  -1.17  -0.185  1.29     2.00 
4  0.162  0.237 -0.508  0.228   -0.462
5 -1.19  -1.32  -0.678  1.60     1.14 
6  0.888  0.404 -0.173 -0.996   -0.627

fitted_value <- rep(0,nrow(wdbc))

for(i in 1:nrow(wdbc)){
test<-wdbc[i,]
training<-wdbc[-i,]
m=lad(PE ~ ., data=training, method="BR")

co.data = coef(m)
x = cbind(1, as.matrix(test[, !(colnames(test) %in% "PE")]))
fitted_value[i] <- x %*% co.data
    }

R2<-(cor(wdbc$PE,fitted_value)^2) 
SAD<-sum(abs(wdbc$PE-fitted_value))

c(round(SAD,2) ,round(R2,2))
```

**NOTE 1**

The data used in the question is only for an explanation because in my project I have many datasets with high dimensions.

**EDIT**

Based on @Dominic van Essen answer, I used the following R code using `parSapply` function from `parallel` package but it takes time more than the for loop.

```
library(parallel)

mycluster=makeCluster(detectCores()-1) 
wdbc <- read_excel("Folds5x2_pp.xlsx") 
wdbc[] <- lapply(wdbc, scale)
clusterExport(mycluster,c("lad","wdbc")) 

fitted_value = parSapply(mycluster,seq_len(nrow(wdbc)),function(i) {
    for(i in 1:nrow(wdbc)){
    test<-wdbc[i,]
    training<-wdbc[-i,]
    m=lad(PE ~ ., data=training, method="BR")

    co.data = coef(m)
    x = cbind(1, as.matrix(test[, !(colnames(test) %in% "PE")]))
  }
    return (x %*% co.data)
})
```

**NOTE 2**

I have 8 cores, and "PE" is the dependent variable in my data set.

Comment: Just a quick comment: the apply family of functions do not vectorize operations in R. They are convenient wrapper functions for getting things done, but you will not generally see big speed improvements.

Comment: @bzki, I see. So, do you think there is a way to speed my code? Because I have many datasets with different dimensions which will take too much time.

Comment: I unfortunately don't know the answer to your question (someone more knowledgeable than me can answer). For linear regression with least squares fitting, there is a simple way of getting the LOO CV error by just fitting the model once: https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/loocv-linear-models/. I don't know if there is something similar for least absolute deviation fitting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily re-write your loop using `sapply` instead of `for...`, although, as bzki commented, this alone will not speed-up your code:

```
# sapply version:
fitted_value = sapply(seq_len(nrow(wdbc)),function(i) {
    # put all the gubbins in here
    # ...
    return (x %*% co.data)
})
```

However, if you have multiple cores available on your computer, or - even better - access to a server with many processors, then an `sapply` loop can easily be parallelized using `parSapply` from the 'parallel' package, as shown in this example:

```
# slow sapply loop (takes 12s):
data=123
answer = sapply(1:12,function(i) {
    Sys.sleep(1)
    return(data+i)
})
# faster parallel version (takes 4s on my laptop with 4 cores):
library(parallel)
mycluster=makeCluster(detectCores()-1) # leave 1 core available for system 
data=123
clusterExport(mycluster,"data") # specify variable(s) that should be available to parallel function
answer = parSapply(mycluster,1:12,function(i) {
    Sys.sleep(1)
    return(data+i)
})
stopCluster(mycluster)
```

Comment: Are such parallel versions of functions available for other packages as well (tidyverse for example)?

Comment: You could use the furrr package which allows you to use parallel functions like map, map2, pmap, etc from the purrr package.

Comment: @jeza - that's annoying, and I'm unfortunately not familiar with the particular ```lad()``` and ```coef()``` functions that you're using to be able to help if these are part of your problem.  But I have a couple of Qs: 1. did you check that your computer has multiple cores available to parallelize (what is output of ```detectCores()```?); 2. What is ```PE``` in your function?  Is it another variable that you should also make available to the parallel function?

Comment: @Dominic van Essen, I have 8 cores, "PE" is the dependent variable in my data set.

Comment: @jeza - can you verify that the 'parallel' example that I posted does indeed run on your computer more quickly than the non-parallel sapply version?  If this is the case (and so the slowness is linked to the particular functions you're using) then I'm afraid I don't have another suggestion...

Comment: @Dominic van Essen, Yes it is, I think the slowness is related to the for loop I used inside the parSapply.

Comment: @jeza - Ok - I didn't notice this.  You don't need the ```for...``` loop.  The ```parSapply``` should do this itself.  Try simply deleting the ```for...``` line and the corrsponding ```}``` at the bottom.

Comment: @Dominic van Essen, thank you so much. Now it works much faster. I will definitely find a source to learn those stuff since I am working with high dimensions data.